# How do I loop a while loop in C++

Tags: c++, while-loop

Im new to programing in a whole and I was wondering how I could loop my while loop. I'm making a calculator and i've gotten to a part where I have the program ask whether or not the user wants to end the program, if the user answers "Yes" the program will end; however I have noticed that if the user answers "No" the program will just keep on working and not ask the question again. Is there a way where I can have it ask the question again?

```
  while (response != "Yes" && response != "No") {
        cout << "Would you like to end the program? Yes or No" << endl;
        cin >> response;

        if (response == "Yes") {
            calculator_running = false;
        } else if (response == "No") {
            calculator_running = true;
        } else {
            cout << "Please choose a valid response" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Typing either "Yes" or "No" as shown will end the loop. The difference is what you set `calculator_running` to. This question is missing a [example]. The answer will depend on what the rest of your program is doing with that `calculator_running` variable.

Answer (score 1):

Best practice is to split code to smaller pieces to keep concerns separated.

```cpp
bool promptYesNo(const std::string& reason)
{
    std::cin.clear(); // clear any error flags on cin
    std::cout << reason << "\nType \"Yes\" or \"No\": ";
    std::string answear;
    while (std::cin >> answear) {
       if (answear == "Yes") return true;
       if (answear == "No") return false;
       std::cout << "Please select \"Yes\" or \"No\": ";
    }
    // here standard input has ended, so terminating application:
    std::exit(1);
}

while (!promptYesNo("Would you like to end the program?")) {
    ...
}
```

Note that `std::cin.clear();` will protect you from invalid state of `std::cin`. Most probably this is source of your problems. For example some part of program was reading `int` value, but you have provided a letters. This setts error flags on `cin` and any later reads will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `calculator_running` to be checked in the while-part of the loopo, something like this:

```
calculator_running = true;
while (calculator_running)
...
```

Lke this, once you enter "Yes", that variable will be put to false, and you'll jump out of the loop.
The main trick with while-loops is that you always need to set the condition to true, just before you start the while-loop.

Comment: I have it set to true at the beginning of my code, but my question is, is there a way to make it repeat after someone answers no?

Comment: using the conditional `while(calculator_running)` will repeat after a "No" entry because `calculator_running` remains true in the path that "No" is entered

Comment: You can always use a variable, like `calculator_counter` and set it first to 3. Your while-loop checks if `calculator_counter` equals zero, the "Yes" answer puts it to zero, and the "No" answer just lowers it with 1 (`calculator_counter--`).

Answer (score 0):

> I have noticed that if the user answers "No" the program will just keep on working and not ask the question again

That's what you told the program to do!

If you don't want an entry of `"No"` to end the loop, take it out of the condition:

```
while (response != "Yes") {
```

Or, use your boolean, which is a bit "cleaner" (but ultimately has the same effect):

```
while (calculator_running) {
```